# The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Server key"

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, glassfish, mssql-jdbc

I gave up! Tried everything and failed. Every time I try to deploy that .ear file (as in title of this post), I get that error:

```
Caused by: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Unknown KeySpec type: java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec
```

I include a stack trace below:

```
[#|2015-08-11T14:47:30.185+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Server key". ClientConnectionId:a3f21831-fbc0-491c-9691-2b28500d7d2b
Error Code: 0
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Server key". ClientConnectionId:a3f21831-fbc0-491c-9691-2b28500d7d2b
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.connectInternal(DatasourceAccessor.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.connectInternal(DatabaseAccessor.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.connect(DatasourceAccessor.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ConnectionPool.buildConnection(ConnectionPool.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ExternalConnectionPool.startUp(ExternalConnectionPool.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.connect(ServerSession.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.login(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:211)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:120)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:495)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:233)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:207)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:148)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Server key". ClientConnectionId:a3f21831-fbc0-491c-9691-2b28500d7d2b
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:123)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Server key". ClientConnectionId:a3f21831-fbc0-491c-9691-2b28500d7d2b
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:190)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:165)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:160)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:113)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Server key". ClientConnectionId:a3f21831-fbc0-491c-9691-2b28500d7d2b
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:103)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.addResource(ConnectionPool.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResourceAndAddToPool(ConnectionPool.java:1512)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResources(ConnectionPool.java:944)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.initPool(ConnectionPool.java:230)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.internalGetResource(ConnectionPool.java:511)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getResource(ConnectionPool.java:381)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResourceFromPool(PoolManagerImpl.java:245)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:170)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.getResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:338)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:301)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Server key". ClientConnectionId:a3f21831-fbc0-491c-9691-2b28500d7d2b
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResource(ConnectionPool.java:1189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:98)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Server key". ClientConnectionId:a3f21831-fbc0-491c-9691-2b28500d7d2b
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:110)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:907)
    ... 90 more
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Server key". ClientConnectionId:a3f21831-fbc0-491c-9691-2b28500d7d2b
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:129)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:87)
    ... 91 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Server key". ClientConnectionId:a3f21831-fbc0-491c-9691-2b28500d7d2b
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1667)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1668)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1323)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnectionInternal(SQLServerDataSource.java:621)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnection(SQLServerDataSource.java:57)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:115)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Server key
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.throwSSLException(Handshaker.java:927)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:202)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:943)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1618)
    ... 98 more
Caused by: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Unknown KeySpec type: java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.asymmetric.ec.KeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:304)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.HandshakeMessage$ECDH_ServerKeyExchange.<init>(HandshakeMessage.java:922)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:198)
    ... 105 more
```

I tried many, way too many things, the last attempt was: to generate self-signed certificate in MS SQL server (that is the database server I am trying to use through the agency of JDBC as a data store for that java application packaged in .ear file), added to trusted certificates in ms sql server. I was trying not to use ssl, but it looks like it needs it any way since stack trace reads:

```
Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Server key". ClientConnectionId:a3f21831-fbc0-491c-9691-2b28500d7d2b
```

Then I have exported that certificate to a directory on c drive (.cer file) and imported it into trusted store in JDBC. I set

```
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias
```

to point to the alias for the imported certificate in JDBC trust store, which is by the way under domain/domain_name/config directory in glassfish server.

And ...

... And I still get the same exception as above described. I am trying to FIGHT with this error for more than 2 weeks by now and I had lost any hope, unless, you guys know/have any idea what to do?

EDIT:
I would also add, that I can establish JDBC connection from Eclipse for instance and when I run this simple app from Eclipse, it works fine:

```
package sqlserver;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            System.out.println("Failed to register the driver.");
        }

        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:3306;" +
                   "databaseName=target;integratedSecurity=true;";
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String s = "use target";
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Colori";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()){
                int id  = rs.getInt("Id");
                String desc = rs.getString("Descrizione");
                System.out.println(id + " : " + desc);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Problem occurs, only, when I try to deploy application to Glassfish, as if magically it was completely cut out from SQL Server for good.

I am using SQL Server, Java EE 6 Persistence Framework, Eclipse Link, sqljdbc4 and Glassfish 3.1.2.2.

Comment: I bet, I am doing it all wrong, but how and where ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here there goes an answer, all it took was basically to delete glassfish installation and install it again. I have also exported self signed ssl certificate (which I have previously generated for SQL Server, using MSSQL utility -> mmc console) to a directory on C drive: `C:\MSSQL_exports`, from there I have imported it to `{glassfish_installation_directory}\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain_name\config` into `cacerts.jks` and `keystore.jks`. I have also imported above mentioned certificate `(.cer file)` into `cacerts` file of my jre installation in the directory: `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\security`.

As explained certificate was created as a .cer file using mmc utility which comes with SQL Server and Mcrosoft SQL Server Management Studio installation. That certificate was also installed into SQL Server as SSL certificate, using SQL Server Configuration Manager `(Server Network Configuration > Protocols for SQLEXPRESS > Properties > Certificate tab, force encryption - NOT SET)`.

All the certificate imports were done using keytool utility with

> -alias certy6

That matters only in a context of the last thing I did, which was to set jvm property in domain.xml file (which can be found here `{glassfish_installation_directory}\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain_name\config)` as follows:

> -Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=certy6

Btw... I have also set `eclipselink.ddl-generation` property to `update` when setting up EclipseLink (I was using that too!) configuration for my Java application which I was trying to deploy to Glassfish.

Here is a link, how to do it:
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/persistenceproperties_ref.htm

I have also corrected few other things which looked wrong in EclipseLink configuration, in particular type of database was set to `mysql`, so I changed it to `sqlserver`. So if you use it too (EclipseLink that is), just make sure your EclipseLink configurations are correct and perhaps test them (as I did) through an agency of some testing app from withing Eclipse (I mean IDE here!).

Restart SQL Server and Glassfish, and apparently now it works.
Hope, this can help someone one day to solve his or her problems with a little bit less of a hassle than that which I had to go through and despite having moderate number of views, I could not get any response to my problem. It was also very hard to find any useful documentation on the internet related to this, so maybe now I will live this for the benefit of others.

Please vote up the answer, if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem and solved it without reinstalling Glassfish.

Turns out that the certificate of the server where MSSQL was running had been renewed. Verify this by opening the certificate (e.g. with Windows Certificate manager and check date of creation)

First, export the server certificate (base-64, cer) and root certificate (base-64, cer)
Then, open command line as admin
Import the root certificate to cacert & import the server certificate to keystore:

```
<path_to_JavaJDK>\bin>keytool -keystore "<path_to_domain>\config\cacerts.jks"  -import -alias <aliasName> -file <path_to_root_ca.cer>
<path_to_JavaJDK>\bin>keytool -keystore "<path_to_domain>\config\keystore.jks"  -import -alias <aliasName> -file <path_to_server_certificate.cer>
```

Finally, restart glassfish